# Obtaining intermediate certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, game-center

I need to verify a public certificate from Apple to authenticate a Game Center user server side (using [generateIdentityVerificationSignatureWithCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLocalPlayer/generateIdentityVerificationSignatureWithCompletionHandler)).

I have no problem getting the certificate from Apple (eg. https://sandbox.gc.apple.com/public-key/gc-sb.cer), but it is signed with an intermediate certificate (VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA) which in turn then is signed by a trusted root certificate (VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5).

Obviously I need the intermediate certificate to authenticate the apple certificate- what would the normal approach be to obtaining intermediate certificates?

How should I go about getting it for this purpose?